# MyBatis Callable with SQL temp variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, mybatis

I am trying to get a Stored Procedure to use SQL date instead of Java date.
But I want to do this without modifying the SP.

This is what I would like to do.

```xml
    <select id="updateThing" statementType="CALLABLE">
        {
            DECLARE @tmp DATETIME
            SET @tmp = GETDATE()

            CALL  dbo.thingUpdate (
                #{..., javaType=java.lang.Integer, jdbcType = NUMERIC},
                ...,
                <choose>
                    <when test="datePassed != null">
                        @tmp,
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        NULL,
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
                ...
            )
        }
    </select>
```

I have tried moving the bracers around and I have tried doing the `GETDATE()` in place and using `TIMESTAMP`, but all of them seem to trigger an exception.

In the case of the above version the error is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '{'
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You should try to find a syntax that works with plain JDBC first (if there is). Then it may work with MyBatis as well. BTW, what is the difference between 'SQL date' and 'Java date'? It seems to make more sense to pass a calculated `java.time.LocalDateTime` or something (can be null) as a parameter.

Comment: The difference was timezone I think. We wanted to have 1 source of truth for new dates. It was doing what you suggested, but then an issue arose that the times were out and that's why I am looking at letting the DB handle it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but the legacy classes like `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` are affected by the client's timezone while the new `java.time` a.k.a. JSR-310 classes are not. Anyway, thx for the explanation and hope you get the answer.:)

Comment: I couldn't solve this. I ended up doing another update do add the date and then passing null for the date in the SP.

Comment: Another work around would be to do a select for getdate() in the java separately and then pass it to the SP from Java. Also not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another stored procedure that acts as a wrapper for the existing one. It should get the date if needed and invoke the original stored procedure.

Comment: Good call. This did come up as one of our options, I think it is a good solution.